# C# WebBrowser1 Click A Href - How To

Tags: c#, hyperlink, browser, click

I have a WebBrowser1 object. I can load page successfully. I want to click an a href element. It has to be same as user click because it executes some javascripts. How can i do that ?

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 C# .net 4.0

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the element has an `id` like this

```
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com" id="hrefId">TestLink</a>
```

you can do something like this.

```
var element = webBrowser1.Document.All["hrefId"];
if(element != null )
{
    webBrowser1.Select();
    element.Focus();
    SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
}
```

Comment: But what if it does not have id how can i do that ?

Comment: @PokemonCraft [`HtmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.aspx) has multiple ways to locate elements. Getting element by ID is the easiest as IDs are unique. You can also get elements by tag name using `GetElementsByTagName()` and iterate thru the returned collection and pick which element you want.

Comment: @PokemonCraft It depends. Given a html page, in your case, how do you identify the element that you want to programatically click?

Comment: I am guessing iterating via a tag elements would solve. It has a unique domain url so iterating via a tags and when indexof that url exist click same way as mouse would solve problem.